# C# Performance is slow on list comparisons using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, search, optimization

I have a list of this model

```
public Class Contact
{
   public string MobileNumber {get;set;}
   public string PhoneNumber2 {get;set;}
}
```

I have a method that compares this list against of list of phone numbers and returns non matching values

```
private List<ContactDto> GetNewContactsNotFoundInCrm(ContactPostModel model) 
{
    var duplicates = GetAllNumbers(); // Returns a List<string> of 5 million numbers
    var mobile = duplicates.Select(x => x.MobilePhone).ToList();
    var telephone2 = duplicates.Select(x => x.Telephone2).ToList();

    // I'm trying to compare Telephone2 and MobilePhone against the
    // duplicates list of 5 million numbers. It works, but it's slow
    // and can take over a minute searching for around 5000 numbers.

    return model.Contacts
        .Where(y => 
            !mobile.Contains(y.Phonenumber.ToPhoneNumber()) &&
            !telephone2.Contains(y.Phonenumber.ToPhoneNumber()) && 
            !mobile.Contains(y.Phonenumber2.ToPhoneNumber()) && 
            !telephone2.Contains(y.Phonenumber2.ToPhoneNumber()))
        .ToList();
}

// Extension method used
public static string ToPhoneNumber(this string phoneNumber)
{
    if (phoneNumber == null || phoneNumber == string.Empty)
        return string.Empty;

    return phoneNumber.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "")
        .Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "");
}
```

What data structure can I use to compare the `Mobile` and `Telephone2` to the list of 5 million numbers for better performance?

Comment: Look at `HashSet`

Comment: 1) Try to use `HashSet<T>` instead of `List<T>` 2) cache the `ToPhoneNumber()` results, you call this a lot of times for all elements.

Comment: Using `ToHashSet` instead of `ToList` and you could just do one hash set of the mobile and telephone2 numbers since you always compare to both sets.

Comment: From where do you get you Telephone Numbers(the internas of GetAllNumbers)?  To get it fast it would be ideal that the source already prepared to being fast for such operations, like having an index there or something like that.

Comment: @RufusL: That's not a string.Contains, that's a collection.Contains.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior oh, of couse. thanks!

Comment: In addition to using `HashSet` you have `y.Phonenumber2.ToPhoneNumber()` being called 4 times per contact with each one  calling `string.Replace` 4 times. This might be a source of unnecessary garbage churn. To address the first issue change your where to use a function body, ie add `{` `}` and `return`.The `.ToPhoneNumber` result can then be assigned to a local `var`. To address the multiple replace string churn maybe switch it to a regular expression replacement. Overall though this seems like a job for the database to manage via a sproc call.

Comment: `if (phoneNumber == null || phoneNumber == string.Empty)  return string.Empty;` could be written `if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(phoneNumber))  return string.Empty;`

Comment: I'd also want to consider the context - how often is `GetNewContactsNotFoundInCrm` called? Can you create the `GetAllNumbers()` once and pass it along for multiple checks? How often are new  numbers added? Can you cache the result locally and reduce the amount of external latency pulling the lists?

Comment: [Enumerable.Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: `Enumerable.Except` uses `HashSet` internally to improve lookup performance. You want to use the overload which allows to pass in a custom `IEqualityComparer` as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Except`.
`Enumerable.Except` uses `HashSet` internally to improve lookup performance. You want to use the overload which allows to pass in a custom `IEqualityComparer` as an argument.

Also note that `ToList()` is a LINQ query finalizer. Means that `ToList()` executes the LINQ expression immediately - which results in a complete iteration over the collection. LINQ's power is that queries are executed deferred, which improves the performance significantly. All sub-queries (whether chained or split up in separate statements) are merged into one single iteration using `yield return` internally:

Good performance:

```
// Instead of two iterations, LINQ will defer both 
// iterations and merge them into a single iteration
var filtered = collection.Where(); // Deferred iteration #1
var projected = filtered.Select(); // Deferred iteration #2
var results = projected.ToList(); // Results in one single iteration
```

Bad performance:

```
// LINQ will execute each iteration immediately
// resulting in two complete iterations
var filtered = collection.Where().ToList(); // Executed iteration #1
var projected = filtered.Select().ToList(); // Executed iteration #2
```

You should avoid to call a finalizer before you actually want to execute the query to significantly improve the performance:

```
// Executes deferred
var mobile = duplicates.Select(x => x.MobilePhone);
```

Instead of:

```
// Executes immediately
var mobile = duplicates.Select(x => x.MobilePhone).ToList();
```

Also note that each `Enumerable.Contains` executes a separate iteration. `Contains` is a finalizer and will execute immediately:

```
return model.Contacts
  .Where(y => 
    !mobile.Contains(y.Phonenumber.ToPhoneNumber()) // Iteration #1
      && !telephone2.Contains(y.Phonenumber.ToPhoneNumber()) // Iteration #2
      && !mobile.Contains(y.Phonenumber2.ToPhoneNumber()) // Iteration #3
      && !telephone2.Contains(y.Phonenumber2.ToPhoneNumber())) // Iteration #4
  .ToList(); // Iteraion #5
```

Worst case iterates over `n elements * 4 Enumerable.Contains * 5*10^6 reference elements in mobile and telephone2` - only for comparison!

### `Enumerable.Except`

**ContactEqualityComparer.cs**

```
class ContactEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Contact>
{
  public bool Equals(Contact contact1, Contact contact2)
  {
    if (ReferenceEquals(contact1, contact2))      
      return true;
    else if (ReferenceEquals(contact1, null) || ReferenceEquals(contact2, null))
      return false;
    else if (contact1.MobileNumber.Equals(contact2.MobileNumber, StringComparoison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
      && contact1.PhoneNumber2.Equals(contact2.PhoneNumber2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

  // Will be used by Enumerable.Except to generate item keys 
  // for the lookup table
  public int GetHashCode(Contact contact)
  {
    unchecked
    {
      return ((contact.MobileNumber != null 
        ? contact.MobileNumber.GetHashCode() 
        : 0) * 397) ^ (contact.PhoneNumber2 != null 
          ? contact.PhoneNumber2.GetHashCode() 
          : 0);
    }
  }
}
```

**Contact.cs**
Consider to use two properties for each data: one property for computations and one for display e.g. `MobileNumber` and `MobileNumberDisplay`. The computation properties should be numeric.

```
public class Contact : IEqualityComparer<Contact>
{
  private string mobileNumber;
  public string MobileNumber
  {
    get => this.mobileNumber;
    set => this.mobileNumber = value.ToPhoneNumber();
  }

  private string phoneNumber2;
  public string PhoneNumber2 
  { 
    get => this.phoneNumber2; 
    set => this.phoneNumber2 = value.ToPhoneNumber();
  }
    
  public string ToPhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)
  {
    if (phoneNumber == null || phoneNumber == string.Empty)
        return string.Empty;

    return phoneNumber.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "")
        .Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "");
  }
}
```

**Example**

```
private List<Contact> GetNewContactsNotFoundInCrm(ContactPostModel model) 
{    
  List<Contact> duplicates = GetAllNumbers();

  return model.Contacts
    .Except(duplicates, new ContactEqualityComparer())
    .ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: This won't work. It won't even compile. `union` is an `IEnumerable<string>`, so it can't be passed as an argument to `Except(IEnumerable<Contact>)`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Thank you. After reviewing the original code, I noticed that the OP added a misleading comment. According to the `Select` query the local variable `duplicates` appears to be a `List<Contact>` instead of a `List<string>`. This would further simplify the code: instead of converting the `Contact` to a string, it should be preferred to operate on the `Contact` directly to safe the transformation costs.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Anyway, the goal must be to remove the _four!_ `Enumerable.Contains` queries, which will iterate ~5 million reference elements _for each element_ in the source collection (n * 4 * 5*10^6).

Comment: I understand your initial confusion. I agree that avoiding `Enumerable.Contains` is important, and I think that can be done by changing those to `HashSet<>.Contains`. It likely won't matter whether we're doing 5000 or 20000 of those calls, once we've turned that operation into an `O(1)` operation.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a HashSet will probably solve your problems:

```
    var mobile = new HashSet<string>(duplicates.Select(x => x.MobilePhone));
    var telephone2 = new HashSet<string>(duplicates.Select(x => x.Telephone2));
```

There are other performance improvements you can make, but they'll be micro-optimizations compared to avoiding iterating over 5 million items for each number you check.

Answer (score 1):

One good option here is to try removing the need for the phone number conversions (call to `ToPhoneNumber` method) over each iteration step, by making both regular numbers (the one you convert ToPhoneNumber), telephone number and mobile numbers and `telephone2` numbers to compared by the same format.

The other thing to improve over the query is to cach the calls for mobile and telephone2 numbers. You can move their calculation outside of the `GetNewContactsNotFoundInCrm` method and acquire only when there is a new change in data.

Finally, consider using [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netcore-3.1) for removing the need to have duplicates and make fast comparisons.

---

Side note:

If you are dealing with the database elements, consider moving this logic to SQL [Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/walkthrough-using-only-stored-procedures-csharp).